# vue-router Uncaught ReferenceError: router is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm reviewing Vue and it's router component, although I'm having some issues getting the router component to work. Error in console below:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: router is not defined

Hi all,

I'm importing the Vue and VueRouter into an `index.html` and trying my best to read the documentation to get the router initialized, but cannot seem to it working.

In `index.html`:

```html
<script type="module" src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
```

In `main.js`:

```js
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: 'home', component: home } 
  ]
});

var app = new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ...etc
```

Help would be appreciated...

Many thanks.

Comment: If the second code sample is from `main.js` then I would suggest reordering your `<script>` tags to put `main.js` last. Otherwise, could you include the full stacktrace for the error?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `import VueRouter from 'vue-router'` **AND** `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>`

import means it's expecting it as an npm dependency which will be bundled in the `main.js` file when compiled.

you need to run `npm install -save vue-router` or remove the `import ...` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you do not have any building process, and you load Vue and Vue Router directly in browser.

To make everything work, you should follow next steps:

1. Change the order of scripts, so your `main.js` goes last. Because you need Vue and Vue Router already be loaded before you init your application.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

2. Remove `import` from your `main.js` as it runs directly in browser.

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)

var router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: 'home', component: home } 
  ]
});

var app = new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ...etc
```